# Is it possible to handle R.array.string-array-name through a string variable in android studio?

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, string

I have **strings.xml**  file like below:

```
<string-array name="planet">
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
</string-array>
```

My **activity_main.xml** code segment for my spinner:

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

My **MainActivity.java** code segment:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planet, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Now I want to do this code like below:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String arrayName = "planet";
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.arrayName, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

May I get the help that if it is possible then how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Integer Id of String Array from `string.xml` like below Code .

```
String arrayName = "planet";
int arrayName_ID= getResources().getIdentifier(arrayName , "array",this.getPackageName()); 
// You had used "arrayName"
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(arrayName_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String value = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.value_array)[selectedIndex];
```

and you get all String[] without specifying index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string array like

```
 ArrayList<String> string_array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_name)));

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,string_array);
```